# Can someone tell how to correct a syntax error and formatting in my python code? My output keeps saying "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the link to my python
on code.My output says the syntax is invalid and I have no idea how to fix that.

I have provided an explanation in the form of comment lines that are included in the code.
Please read the comment lines to understand the code easily.
Save the above python code file and words.txt file in the same folder on your computer.
Run the code and check your output.

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zXREVhExqenCQyhN3KroJWHab7F9fckCxNtaR0A1HvI/edit?usp=sharing

```
 def get_frequency():
 word_frequency = {}
# Opening text file in read mode
File = open('words.txt', 'r')
# Loop over text file line by line
for line in File:
# Removing the extra spaces at both ends
    line = line.strip()
    # Converting line into list of words
    words = line.split()
    # Loop over words list word by word
    for word in words:
        # If word already in word_frequency dictionary
        # then incrementing value
        if word in word_frequency:
            word_frequency[word] += 1
        else:
            # If word not in word_frequency dictionary
            # then creating new key-value pair in the 
             dictionary
            word_frequency[word] = 1
       # Closing the text file
       File.close()
    # Returning word_frequency dictionary return word_frequency




 def get_lines():
all_lines = {}
# Opening text file in read mode
File = open('words.txt', 'r')
# Variable to keep track line number
line_num = 1
   # Loop over text file line by line
     for line in File:
    # Removing the extra spaces at both ends of the line
      line = line.strip()
    # Converting the line into list of words
    words = line.split()
    # Adding new key-value pair to the all_lines dictionary
    all_lines[line_num] = words
    # Incrementing the value of line_num
    line_num += 1
# Closing the text file
File.close()
word_lines = {}
# Loop over word_frequency dictionary key by key 
for word in get_frequency():
    # Loop over all_lines dictionary key by key
    for num in all_lines:
        # Adding key-value pair to the word_lines dictionary
        if word in all_lines[num]:
            if word in word_lines:
                word_lines[word].append(num)
            else:
                word_lines[word] = [num]
# Returning the word_lines dictionary
return word_lines




      def print_word_info(dict1, dict2):
       # Printing heading
        print("               WORD INFO")
         print("-------------------------------------")
            print("WORD           FREQUENCY        LINES")
           print("-------------------------------------")
            # Loop over sorted keys of dict1
          for word in sorted(dict1.keys()):
           # Printing word and frequency
          print("{:<18}{:<14}".format(word, dict1[word]), end='')
          # Loop over numbers in the line numbers list of current 
           word
         for num in dict2[word]:
        # Printing line number
        print(num, end=' ')
    print()




          # main() function
        def main():

         # Function call to display summary of words in the text 
         file
         print_word_info(get_frequency(), get_lines())



           # Function call to main()
            main()
```

Comment: You need to post your code as formatted text here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I fixed the problem.

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors are usually the result of improper formatting of your code.  In your case, the errors stem from improper indentation.  In future please refer to [The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/) for guidance on correcting such errors.  I have taken the time to correct your indentation errors as best I can surmise from your code as shown below.  This corrected code will run, however, since I have no idea of what you are trying to do, I can't say the code is correct.

```
def get_frequency():
    word_frequency = {}
    # Opening text file in read mode
    File = open('words.txt', 'r')
    # Loop over text file line by line
    for line in File:
        # Removing the extra spaces at both ends
        line = line.strip()
        # Converting line into list of words
        words = line.split()
        # Loop over words list word by word
        for word in words:
            # If word already in word_frequency dictionary
            # then incrementing value
            if word in word_frequency:
                word_frequency[word] += 1
            else:
                # If word not in word_frequency dictionary
                # then creating new key-value pair in the 
                dictionary
                word_frequency[word] = 1
    # Closing the text file
    File.close()
    # Returning word_frequency dictionary 
    return word_frequency  
def get_lines():
    all_lines = {}
    # Opening text file in read mode
    File = open('words.txt', 'r')
    # Variable to keep track line number
    line_num = 1
    # Loop over text file line by line
    for line in File:
        # Removing the extra spaces at both ends of the line
        line = line.strip()
        # Converting the line into list of words
        words = line.split()
        # Adding new key-value pair to the all_lines dictionary
        all_lines[line_num] = words
        # Incrementing the value of line_num
        line_num += 1
    # Closing the text file
    File.close()
    word_lines = {}
    # Loop over word_frequency dictionary key by key 
    for word in get_frequency():
        # Loop over all_lines dictionary key by key
        for num in all_lines:
            # Adding key-value pair to the word_lines dictionary
            if word in all_lines[num]:
                if word in word_lines:
                    word_lines[word].append(num)
            else:
                word_lines[word] = [num]
    # Returning the word_lines dictionary
    return word_lines
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a Python program that reads the contents of a text file and displays the frequency of every 
unique word as well as the line numbers that the word is found on.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ufVxjRU

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: So does the code solve your problem or not.  If not where does it go wrong?